# How to split json using EvaluateJsonPath processor in NiFi

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-nifi

I want to split and transfer the json data in NiFi, Here is my json structure look like this;
I want to split json by id1,id2 array of json transfer to respective processor group say example processor_group a,b. I tried with evaluate json path $.id1,$.id2 but i didn't get exact solution. Can you please help me out from this issue;

```
{
    "id1": [{
        "u_name": "aa"
    }, {
        "addr": "bb"
    }],
    "id2": [{
        "u_name": "aa"
    }, {
        "addr": "bb"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Title of question doesn't match ask for a method to split....  also I would avoid posting on multiple platforms,  most of us are on both.  My reply below is from Cloudera Community.

Answer (score 0):

The processor you're looking for is `SplitJSON`.
Configure it as follows:
[image]

Then, you'll receive two FlowFiles:
[image]

First one will contain the `id1`:

```
[{
        "u_name": "aa"
    }, {
        "addr": "bb"
    }]
```

second one will contain `id2`:

```
[{
        "u_name": "aa"
    }, {
        "addr": "bb"
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get to the values you want with EvaluateJsonPath:

@varun_rathinam Accessing json in an array object via EvaluateJsonPath can be quite confusing.   I also notice the structure of your json is kind of confusing with same values in both.  I have adjusted id2 for cc and dd for testing so that I can tell id1 and id2 values apart.

The solution you want is (see template for exact string values):

[image]

Notice we use the normal tree for each json object ( $.object ) then access the array ( 0, 1 ) then access the array's objects.   Also notice it is possible to access the json object array with or without a . before the [.

Reference:
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/how-to-extract-fields-in-flow-file-which-are-surrounded-by/m-p/208635

You can also find my template during testing of your issue on my GitHub:
https://github.com/steven-dfheinz/NiFi-Templates/blob/master/NiFI_EvaluateJsonPath_Demo.xml